# How to install the Perforce plugin in Eclipse 3.8

Tags: perforce, p4eclipse

How do I install the Perforce plugin (P4Eclipse) in Eclipse 3.8? The Perforce [Plugins & Integrations](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/Perforce/20-User?qt-perforce_downloads_step_3=6#product-21) page only lists Eclipse 4.2 through 4.4. Eclipse 3.8 is the version provided in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.

Comment: With new idea, its now so simple - Just drag and drop the INSTALL from browser to eclipse and you're done: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/p4eclipse probably it would only work with eclipse-Neon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest versions of P4Eclipse no longer supports Eclipse 3, but an older version (2013.1) is still available if hidden.

Choose Help --> Install New Software. After "Work with:" enter `http://www.perforce.com/downloads/http/p4-eclipse/install/3.8`

Under `Perforce Team Provider Core` select `Perforce SCM support`