# What is the URL for the Perforce Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, perforce

What is the URL for the Perforce Eclipse plugin installation site?

I have tried:

```
https://www.perforce.com/downloads
https://www.perforce.com/
http://www.perforce.com/downloads
http://www.perforce.com/
https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-plugin-eclipse-p4eclipse
```

I also tried manually installing.  The documentation on Perforce's website appears to be out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is it for Eclipse Photon:

```
http://www.perforce.com/downloads/http/p4-eclipse/install/4.8
```

[How to install the Perforce plugin in Eclipse 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823408/how-to-install-the-perforce-plugin-in-eclipse-3-8)

Answer (score 1):

For Photon, P4Eclipse 2018.3 supports it and you can grab it from http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r18.3/bin.java/

Then follow the "Installing from a zip file" section in the release notes:
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4eclipsenotes.txt

If you have an Eclipse version <= 4.4, and a Support entitlement, contact Perforce Support.