# How to install the Perforce plugin in Eclipse 4.2

Tags: eclipse, jar, perforce, p4eclipse

I'm trying to install the perforce plugin in Eclipse 4.2. On the official webpage there's only downloadable versions for 4.6 and newer. However trying to use the oldest 4.6 version fails during the installation with following output

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Perforce SCM Support 2017.1.1583678 (com.perforce.team.feature.feature.group 2017.1.1583678)
Missing requirement: Perforce Team Provider UI 2017.1.1583678 (com.perforce.team.ui 2017.1.1583678) requires 'bundle com.google.gson 2.2.4' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Perforce SCM Support 2017.1.1583678 (com.perforce.team.feature.feature.group 2017.1.1583678)
To: com.perforce.team.ui [2017.1.1583678]
```

Since I use IBM's Integration Bus 10.0.0.13 Toolkit I can't upgrade Eclipse to a newer version. The old solution provided here does not work anymore : [How to install the Perforce plugin in Eclipse 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823408/how-to-install-the-perforce-plugin-in-eclipse-3-8) because the download link is dead.

I tried downloading this jar file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar But can't find a documentation that shows how to get Eclipse to use it.

Has anyone had the same problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to install the correct p4eclipse42.zip plugin. It's officially not downloadable anymore and one has to ask perforce support nicely to get a copy.